# PHP problems with flash media server 4.5

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, flash-media-server

I have installed php on my server. Prior to that i have installed flash media server 4.5 streaming edition and i am using the Apache 2.2 supplied with that.
Now, I can see that Php is installed (with php -v) but when i try to access php files, my browser shows them as a text file.
Since I am using the HTTP streaming, i would need to use the apache that comes with FMS.
I have tried reinstalling it, restarting the FMS server, Apache Server but nothing works.

OS: CentOS 5.8 (can't upgrade as FMS doesnt support 6.0 and above)
FMS version: 4.5 ( Streaming )
PHP version installed: 5.3

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you streaming the files on port 80? if apache also listens to port 80 then that will make a problem, to make sure which port apache is listening to try to execute the command "lsof -i:80" and see what is the output

Comment: COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
fmsedge 1558  fms   24u  IPv4 357491423      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
fmsedge 1558  fms   92u  IPv4 357491635      0t0  UDP localhost.localdomain:http 
fmsedge 1558  fms   93u  IPv4 357491636      0t0  UDP vps.lyfe.in:http 
fmsedge 1558  fms   94u  IPv4 357491637      0t0  UDP psql-hubert.downloadquicker.com:http 
fmsedge 1558  fms   95u  IPv4 357491638      0t0  UDP psql-donna.downloadquicker.com:http

Comment: fmsedge 1558  fms   96u  IPv4 357491639      0t0  UDP 192.186.184.20:http 
fmsedge 1558  fms   97u  IPv4 357716310      0t0  TCP vps.lyfe.in:http->103.12.133.76.rev.perfectinternet.in:56319 (ESTABLISHED)

Comment: I dont have that much of experience with Linux.
Sorry for the Inconvenience.

Comment: If your stop you media server and start apache, do you still have the same problem?

Comment: I tried doing it.
now the HTTP doesnt start.
Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]

Comment: That is becuase the apache server shipped with your FMS is already taking the port, you can either change the listening port of the FMS or change the port of your apache web server and i think that changing the FMS is better

Comment: By default FMS uses 1935 and 80.
Should I remove port 80 from there??

Comment: Yes! but if you are using a web player that streams the vidoes from your FMS then they should be strictly called using port 1935, also don't forget to start the other instance of apache, which will listen to port 80

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your problem is due to having 2 apache instances trying to listen to the same port "default ed to 80", i would suggest making the FMS apache port listen to port 1935 instead of 80 and leave the your webserver listens to default, some instructions can be found [**here**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/configadmin/WSE2A5A7B9-E118-496f-92F9-E295038DB7DB.html#WSf6b44f6ae3478e7f6951984812a796dfa61-8000) in order to enable and alter your apache configuration which comes with FMS installation, here is a snippet of what you actually need to do in the fms.ini file "which is contained in the link above":

```
ADAPTOR.HOSTPORT = :1935
```

Instead of

```
ADAPTOR.HOSTPORT = :1935, 80
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I did that. The result is same.

Comment: Do you have PHP-Apache module installed? Are you sure that the other instance of apache is running?